# Regular expression comparison in Assert Statements

Tags: java, junit, testng

Is there any library function available in junit  or testng whichcan compare two strings upto some length (like regular expressions). I have a function which can throw a variety of exceptions, I am trying to figure out how to handle all messages in one simple test case.

Comment: You mean, something like a subclass of `Exception`?

Comment: Are you quite sure this is how you'd want to test this? If it can throw a "variety of exceptions" it sounds more like you have multiple test cases.

Comment: no they are not subclass exceptions.

Comment: I agree, that having multiple test cases is more suitable but the exception message is custom built, and starting few words match for all exceptions so i want to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [ExpectedException#expectMessage](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html#expectMessage(org.hamcrest.Matcher))?

```
@Rule ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

@Test public void yourTest() {
  // One overload takes a string to test "contains".
  expectedException.expectMessage("foo");

  // The other takes a Hamcrest matcher. startsWith is a Hamcrest core matcher.
  expectedException.expectMessage(startsWith("Bar"));

  // If you include the latest Hamcrest source, you can use the brand-new
  // MatchesPattern matcher, which is the regex solution you're looking for.
  expectedException.expectMessage(new MatchesPattern(
      new Pattern("Baz.+\[[0-9]+\]")));

  systemUnderTest.doExceptionThrowingCode();
}
```

See the documentation for [StartsWith](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/core/StringStartsWith.java), or the new code (17 days old!) for [MatchesPattern](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/text/MatchesPattern.java).